# Blackhen Threading Library

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

I am looking for documentation for the Blackhen threading library and am unable to find any.  I have just found one article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/workqueuethreading.aspx?msg=998153).

Can someone please point me to some documention for this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the download for the article.

filename: BlackHenThreadingClassLibrary.chm.

I remember using this library for a 1.1 project.  I liked it.